# How do you do a bicycle-kick?

Tags: ps3, fifa-14

Can you tell me how to do a bicycle-kick in FIFA 14 on PS3?

Answer (score 3):

If you press L2 + kick button while the ball is in the air the player will try to volley it so depending on your position it will be a bicycle-kick